# Cassandra CQL import with schema creation option

Tags: cassandra

I want to migrate 500 tables from mysql to cassandra but do not want to create the schemas in cassandra before migration.

i know the option of CQL-IMPORT in Sqoop but only allows copying data with tables created in cassandra.

Is there any way where i can have all the tables structure copied from MYSQL to Cassandra schema format creation of 500 tables in cassandra with more than 100 columns per table will be time consuming.

please help